# Dangling message-body asset error

Tags: apiblueprint

I was trying the apiblueprint to document the APIs but I am encountering an error (on line 31)  that says "Dangling message-body asset, expected a pre-formatted code block, indent every of it's line by 8 spaces or 2 tabs". I started seeing this error only after I added the table of contents.

If I remove line (34) " ", then error is gone. May be I am missing something here or I may not be clear. Any help on it is appreciable. Thanks

Below is my sample markdown.

```
FORMAT: 1A
---


## [I. Introduction](#def-intro)
1. [Group 1](#def-g1)
    1. [G1 Resource 1](#def-g1-res1)
    2. [G1 Resource 2](#def-g1-res2)
2. [Group 2](#def-g2)
    1. [G2 Resource 1](#def-g2-res1)
    2. [G2 Resource 2](#def-g2-res2)
---

<a name="def-intro"> </a>
# I. Introduction
This is my test API

<a name="def-g1"> </a>
# 1. Group 1
This is group 1 API

<a name="def-g1-res1"> </a>
## 1. G1 Resource 1 [/g1api1]
### g1api1 [GET]
This is g1api1

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
            "response": "ok",
            "resource": "g1api1"
        }

<a name="def-g1-res1"> </a>
## 2. G1 Resource 2 [/g1api2]
This is g1api2
### g1api2 [GET]


+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
        "response": "ok",
        "resource": "g1api2"
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One of your problems is using anchors, in particular the one right before:

### 2. G1 Resource 2 [/g1api2]

You don't need to do this. If you render your documentation without those anchors and look at the left hand column, you can click on the links there. You will notice the related fragment in the browser address bar. You can then just use these fragments in markdown links like:

```
FORMAT: 1A

# My Api
This is my test API

## Table of Contents
1. [Introduction Section](#introduction/introduction-section)
1. [Group 1](#reference/one)

    1. [G1 Resource 1](#reference/one/resource-1)
    2. [G1 Resource 2](#reference/one/resource-2)

## Introduction Section
Blah Blah


# Group One
This is group 1 API

## Resource 1 [/g1api1]
### g1api1 [GET]
This is g1api1

+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
            "response": "ok",
            "resource": "g1api1"
        }

## Resource 2 [/g1api2]
This is g1api2
### g1api2 [GET]


+ Response 200 (application/json)

        {
        "response": "ok",
        "resource": "g1api2"
        }
```

Also, it will help you to read: https://apiary.io/blueprint

You should not be putting numbers before the "Group" and "Resource" keywords as they must come first in defining those sections. Apiary will render short-cuts in the left column for you and as I said above you can re-use the associated fragments in your own markdown links per my example above.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I realized after this post that putting numbers before the "Group" and "Resource" keywords is not correct. Although I read the http://apiary.io/blueprint but could not get concept of short cuts before I read your answer.

Your updated markdown does not show any error through editor but when I try to use it with apiary executable to generate the offline html page, I get below error.

Expected "---", "HOST:" or empty line but "F" found.: Expected "---", "HOST:" or empty line but "F" found. (Line: 1, Column: 1)

Whether apib and md have exactly same syntax?

Comment: I think that Apiblueprint and markdown have different method to parse our document.